# apollo graphql health checks without special headers?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I am running an Apollo GraphQL server on AWS behind a Load Balancer.  The Load Balancer issues health checks to the graphql services.  Unfortunately, I only have limited ability to change how those health checks operate: I can change the URL, but I can't change [the headers](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/elb-fix-failing-health-checks-alb).

This means that if I use [the Apollo CSRF-prevention](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v3/security/cors/#preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf), and point my health checks to a basic graphql query [as recommended](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/monitoring/health-checks/), then the health checks will fail on the resulting 400 status responses.

Is it possible to have graphql-level health checks without editing the headers, and without compromising my server by disabling CSRF-prevention?